# typescript dont listen express server

Tags: typescript, express

I build simple typescript , express server. But dont listened. I cant understand. help me. Here my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "ecommerce",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc --watch --preserveWatchOutput "
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  },
  "devDependencies":{
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.13",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Did you actually run the JS code (`tsc` just compiles TS files to JS, it doesn't run them)?

Comment: dont get error. But not listened.

Comment: tsc create index.js file at dist folder

Answer (score 0):

You are just compiling the code in --watch mode. In order to run your application you need to run the compiled file. In this case, you probably want this `start` script:

```
"start": "node ./dist/index.js",
```

leaving your `package.json` like this:

```js
{
  "name": "ecommerce",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc --watch --preserveWatchOutput",
    "start": "node ./dist/index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  },
  "devDependencies":{
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.13",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  }
}
```